# How can I count actual number of followers when if some users are deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the gem called `acts_as_follower`
Suppose there are 3 users called John, Mike, and Justin.
Each of them are following another 2 people.

When after Mike resigned the service, Mike's `User` record will be deleted, but `Follow` record remains.

```
user = User.find_by_name(`John`)
@follower_users = user.followers(order: 'updated_at DESC', limit: '10')
@follower_users_count = user.followers(order: 'updated_at DESC').count
```

`@follower_users_count` should return 1,  because there is only 1 followers(because Mike doesn't exist anymore)

However, this returns "2" because it's counting the number of `Follow`
How can I obtain actual number of followers in this case?

Comment: Maybe you should call the .stop_following(X) method before deleting

Comment: @Sucrenoir That's the smartest way, but how can I? I'm using Devise's default function of deleting user.

Comment: Can't I just code like this? `@follower_users_count = user.followers.users.count`

Comment: @MKK, just add after_destroy/before_destroy filter to User model

Comment: @mr.The Thanks! what if I'm not doing that? How can I still count with avoiding un-existing user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first: are you using latest version of [acts_as_follower](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower) gem?
I take look at [code](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower/blob/master/lib/acts_as_follower/followable.rb#L10) and here is relation with `:dependent => :destroy`:

```
has_many :followings, :as => :followable, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => 'Follow'
```

So, it should not be a problem, after destroying user - all following relations will be destroyed too. If it not - maybe you are using [paranoia gem](https://github.com/radar/paranoia) or something like this? Please, show me your Gemfile.

> Thanks! what if I'm not doing that? How can I still count with
>   avoiding un-existing user?

If you are not do that, you can do something like this:

```
@follower_users_count = user.followers(order: 'updated_at DESC').select{|f| f.user.present? }.count
```

Also, you can look at [gem code](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower/blob/master/lib/acts_as_follower/followable.rb#L63) and try to join users table to sql request and check for the existence of user.

But this methods is bad practice, it will be better, if you check why `:dependent => :destroy` not working.

Comment: Thanks for the best answer. This is what exactly what I wanted! Especially second line:) Sorry for late reply. and Thanks for your help!!